# Folder named with my gmail account

Tags: directory, gmail

I want to delete a folder named with my gmail account in Ubuntu dock

Comment: What have you tried? What is the error message?

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Are you using any online sync app? [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1506383/edit) and add these details.

Answer (score 0):

It was a link with my Google account, which had created that directory named with my email. Today I deleted the link within my account and the folder in the dock disappeared.